# JQuery Code not deleting the associated dynamically added field when clicked on delete icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Information:** I am new to programming & trying to create a To-Do List. On pressing the create list button a div with class wrap is dynamically made which contains two other div's: 1) input from user with class 'item'. 2) Delete icon with class='fa fa-trash'. All these individual wrap div's are contained inside a master div with class="list"

**Expected o/p:** What I want is that on clicking the delete icon (class="fa fa-trash") the entire associated div with class="wrap" gets deleted i.e. one listitem gets deleted

**Current o/p:** Irrespective of which wrap I try to delete(from the list) by clicking on the delete icon it will always delete the oldest wrap added.

Please let me know why on clicking the delete icon it won't delete the corresponding wrap and instead delete the oldest added item(wrap).

jQuery Code:

```js
var maxvalue=9; //to restrict the number of list items created
var count = 0; //to count the number of list items created
var listitem = '<div class="item">'; //every item i/p by user is in class item
var deleteicon = '<div class="fa fa-trash">'; 
var wrap = '<div class="wrapper" id="dynamic">';//to wrap the deleteicon & user i/p in a div

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#createlistbutton').click(function(){
  var toAdd = $('input[name=newlistitem]').val(); //i/p from user
        if(count<maxvalue)
        {
          $('.list').append(wrap + listitem +toAdd + '</div>' + deleteicon + '</div>' +'</div>');//dynamic adding item
          count +=1;
        }
        
        else
        {
          alert("Not more than 9 list can be created");
        }
      
    $('.fa.fa-trash').on('click',function(){
      
      $(this).parent().remove();//delete parent item(wrap) when clicked on deleteicon
      count -= 1;
     
    });
      
    });
    
});
```

```css
-*{  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-family: "Times New Roman","Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
 /**background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);**/ 
  background-color: #b9d2d4;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-dark.png");
  height:100%;
}

h3{
  color:white;
  margin: 18 0 0 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar{
  height: 10%;
  background-color:#303030;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:15;
  padding:0;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li{
  float:left;
  margin-top:5;
  
}

li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:None;
  padding: 8px;
  color:#ffffff;
   padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align:center;
}

li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

footer p{
   margin-top:25px;
   }

footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:10%;
   width:100%;
   color:#ffffff;
   background:#303030;}
   

   
.sidepanel{
   width:30%;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   height:80%;
   background-color:white;
  }

.inputlist{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
   
}

#createlistbutton{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#303030;
 }

form{
  display:inline-block;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color:lightcyan;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  width=80%;
}

.fa.fa-trash{
  display:inline-block;
}

.list{
  position:inherit;
  width=80%;
  max-height:80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Python Flask App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src-animation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <h3>PYTHON FLASK APP</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
  <main>
  <div class="sidepanel">
    <div class="inputlist">
    <form name="newlistform">
    <input type="text" name="newlistitem"/>
   </form>
   <button id="createlistbutton">Create List</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="list">
   </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>COPYRIGHT &copy 2017 PowerSoft</p>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample: http://jsbin.com/magikewuge/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your example: the delete icon deletes its parent correctly without any issue. There are, however, semantic issues with your code: you are duplicating the ID `dynamic` and remember that IDs must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1Lg0f9ms/

```js
var maxvalue=9; //to restrict the number of list items created
var count = 0; //to count the number of list items created
var listitem = '<div class="item">'; //every item i/p by user is in class item
var deleteicon = '<div class="fa fa-trash">'; 
var wrap = '<div class="wrapper" id="dynamic">';//to wrap the deleteicon & user i/p in a div

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#createlistbutton').click(function(){
   var toAdd = $('input[name=newlistitem]').val(); //i/p from user
    if(count<maxvalue) {
     $('.list').append(wrap + listitem +toAdd + '</div>' + deleteicon + '</div>' +'</div>');//dynamic adding item
      count +=1;
    } else {
      alert("Not more than 9 list can be created");
    }
  });  
   
  $(document).on('click','.fa.fa-trash', function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();//delete parent item(wrap) when clicked on deleteicon
    count -= 1;   
  });
    
});
```

```css
-*{  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-family: "Times New Roman","Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
 /**background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);**/ 
  background-color: #b9d2d4;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-dark.png");
  height:100%;
}

h3{
  color:white;
  margin: 18 0 0 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar{
  height: 10%;
  background-color:#303030;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:15;
  padding:0;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li{
  float:left;
  margin-top:5;
  
}

li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:None;
  padding: 8px;
  color:#ffffff;
   padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align:center;
}

li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

footer p{
   margin-top:25px;
   }

footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:10%;
   width:100%;
   color:#ffffff;
   background:#303030;}
   

   
.sidepanel{
   width:30%;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   height:80%;
   background-color:white;
  }

.inputlist{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
   
}

#createlistbutton{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#303030;
 }

form{
  display:inline-block;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color:lightcyan;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  width=80%;
}

.fa.fa-trash{
  display:inline-block;
}

.list{
  position:inherit;
  width=80%;
  max-height:80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <h3>PYTHON FLASK APP</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
  <main>
  <div class="sidepanel">
    <div class="inputlist">
    <form name="newlistform">
    <input type="text" name="newlistitem"/>
   </form>
   <button id="createlistbutton">Create List</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="list">
   </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>COPYRIGHT &copy 2017 PowerSoft</p>
  </footer>
```

Your code may be running, but that's not the correct way to do.

Since your `.fa.fa-trash` element is generated dynamically, you need to delegate an event from document to `.fa.fa-trash` for deleting.

Comment: Thank You Shiladitya! Could you please tell me why I need to delegate an event from document? what does it actually mean?

Comment: You can't have an event on dynamic elements, so you need to delegate events from document.

Comment: ohh okay!! got it..thank you! :D cant believe I wasted two days on this